# What's with all of the throwaway user accounts? e.g. user1137619

Tags: discussion, meta

Why are there so many "anonymous" accounts asking questions?

Comment: I would never change a username like `user1` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Registration is not required to participate on Stack Exchange; you can read, answer, and suggest edits as an anonymous user, much like on Wikipedia. There are some things you won’t be able to do on the site without registering, like voting and other reputation-based abilities. But even if you establish an account, there's nothing forcing a user to change their default username which was generated when they first signed up.